# Controlling powerpoint through bluetooth windows

Tags: windows, api, bluetooth, powerpoint

Is there any way to control powerpoint presentation running on a windows based PC without any kind of server app that needs to be installed on windows system?
Basically, does windows provide any API over bluetooth by which a programmer can remotely control powerpoint presentation running on the system.

Comment: Most probably not without writing your own BT code on windows. The standard BT profiles don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

All of the Bluetooth stacks for Windows that I've used (Microsoft, Widcomm, BlueSoleil) support the HID Profile (Human Interface Device) which is what keyboards and mice use. So just buy a Bluetooth presenter device and it should work. It will send suitable keystrokes to control powerpoint. Perhaps something like http://www.amazon.co.uk/Targus-Bluetooth-Presenter-compatible-operating/dp/7266001692/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1349865397&sr=8-1

The Microsoft stack also support AVRCP (AV Remote Control Profile) and that can likely be used to control a presentation -- though its purpose is of course more related to music etc.